# Android Google Maps API v2 onInfoWindowClick triggers on create of activity all listeners

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i have a map with a lot of markers. When i add the markers to the map i want to add an onInfoWindowClick Listener to each marker with individual data. I want to load an activety with informations of the marker with the onInfoWindowClick Listener.

The code do not work correct. When the activety is created all the listeners are triggered at the same time and when i click on the infoWindow nothing happens.

```java
private void addMarkerToMap(double lat, double lng, String eventTitle,
            String eventDiscribtion) {
        Marker currentMarker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(eventTitle)
                .snippet(eventDiscribtion));

        onInfoWindowClick(currentMarker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,
                    EventActivity.class);
            nextScreen.putExtra("userId", "" + userId);
            nextScreen.putExtra("eventId", "" + eventId);

            startActivityForResult(nextScreen, 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would implement the onclick behavior within your GoogleMap Object (myMap)

```
myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
  new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
      Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,EventActivity.class);
        nextScreen.putExtra("userId", "" + userId);
        nextScreen.putExtra("eventId", "" + eventId);

        startActivityForResult(nextScreen, 0);
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks that works i found it in this moment but now i have another problem. The listeners ne to created with individual data. I get only the last markers info in each marker.

Comment: I had overcome this problem by storing the Markers in a Hashmap<Marker,Object> defined at the Activity level. That way when the Listener is called I can grab the object associated: `MyObject obj = myHashMap.get(marker);`

Comment: @DotProductSoft Hi I am doing the same approac... here is my code

Answer (score 2):

check out this post about how to associate information or objects to markers:
http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html